# The amplitude of a damped spring with a weight during the 4 first oscillations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, spring

[image: Case study, the oscillation of the spring and the source of coulomb damping]

This is my first time posting anything, but I could not figure out the derivation of the amplitude of the spring for the 4 first oscillations. I am not acquainted with the effect and calculations of damping since I am only in high school. This is an assignment I have, I think I am in over my head, but I have invested too much time in this to change the topic. I figure that the only deviation to the classic coulomb damping where the source of energy dissipation is due to the weight sliding on top of a surface, and the force of friction is constant and does not change, is that the friction coefficient changes as more coils enter the paper cylinder which is compressing the spring *(i believe this affects the friction)*. The values that I have is the frictional force of when the entire spring is within the paper cylinder, the mass of the weight, the initial elongation of the spring (x naught) and the spring constant. [image: classical coulomb damping case] . If anyone can help me with my assignment I would be eternally thankful! If not, I would gladly take any help with deriving the amplitude of the classic coulomb damping case as seen above as a backup. Moreover, If there is any rule that I am breaking with this post, let me know. This is as previously stated, the first time that I post anything, and it is due to pure desperation as I am way in over my head! Thanks in advance!

As to not get the assignment done for me, could any kind souls help me understand what the constants are before the sin and cos in the equation for the amplitude or displacement *x* . It is stated to be derived from the initial conditions, but they often lack any clear description of how that is done. The constants in question are "C1, C2, C3 and C4" as seen in the attached picture below. [image]

Most websites that do cover damping only covers viscous damping to a reasonable degree, coulomb or dry friction damping often take a backseat. So it is quite hard for me to figure out how to tackle this assignment, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! I hope you get some help, but note that we don't answer homework or worked example **type** questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/75633) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/75633). You might want to consider posting on [some other Physics website](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391/75633), such as the [PhysicsForums](https://www.physicsforums.com/forums/homework-and-coursework-questions.152/).

Comment: Oh, ok. Is it okay if I ask about how damping works in general then?

Comment: Of course, just do a check before (google) to confirm it's not already well-known and, if it's still not clear, do ask about it.

Comment: You mention that you have a value for the frictional force. Is this an experiment which you have done? Do you have results?

Comment: Yes, I used a dynamometer to measure the dry friction between the spring and paper cylinder. It was 1.15 ± 0.025 N. The spring constant was 20.46 Kg/m. The initial displacement was 0.053 meters. The mass used was 100mg. The oscillations were carried out in an experiment 15 times, and the averages of the amplitudes were taken and put into a graph which is shown here: https://gyazo.com/5ca1220e1d7e012d914aebfb22ec8c7d . I noticed that there was a trend with the amplitude decay, it was as seen in this screenshot https://gyazo.com/81150642375f138c3d654c3a5f5d2449 . The first amplitude deviates

Comment: (*Continues from last edit*) from it due to there being static friction present in the beginning which is greater than the kinetic friction, hence the energy dissipation is greater in that instance. And thank you so much for the expression for the friction, I knew it deviated from the second picture but I did not know how exactly and my teacher advised me to ignore it in the calculations and mention it in the discussion, but I don't need to do that now. If I redo the measurements for friction, and equate the force reading to (CL)/(L0 + x) then i can calculate C, since L, L0 and x is known

Comment: Are you sure that this cannot be solved empirically? I managed to do the ma=-kx + F_r with the help of some of my friends before, but thank you so much for explaining it. And thank you for including a new expression for the frictional force, I'm gonna try to solve that one and see if I am able to. (I forgot to mention that the initial velocity was zero, but you could have deduced that since I mentioned static friction)

Comment: I'm sorry for adding so many comments, but the cosine function I got has no decay, do you know why that is? I used the equation abovementioned with the two constants, since the sine function will equal zero, the remaining function is cosine plus a constant. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Would -sgn(v) be the same as -v/magnitude of v? In which case, how would I calculate the magnitude of v? I think that is the reason I got a cosine equation without any damping, and the reason why I don't even know the first step anymore when trying to solve for x(t) in your equation.

Comment: Yes $sgn(\vec{v})=\vec{v}/|\vec{v}|$. You don't need to calculate $\vec{v}$ or $|\vec{v}|$. As with the text image in your question, $sgn(v)$ is either + or -, so you have two equations, which you solve separately.

Comment: In the solution for the horizontal oscillation, the cosine you got only applies for half a cycle, eg from the extreme point on the left to the extreme point on the right. After each half cycle you have to switch between Case 1 and Case 2. ...  Cosine plus (or minus) a constant $\delta$ is correct. Sorry I have misinformed you about $\delta$ in my answer. The equilibrium point of each cosine is offset from the equilibrium position $x_0$ of the spring by amount $\delta$. The equilibrium point for each half cycle changes from $x_0+\delta$ in one half cycle to $x_0-\delta$ in the next half cycle.

Comment: No I do not think the equation in my answer can be solved *algebraically*, unlike the equation for the horizontal spring. I tried putting it in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/). It only gave me a graph, so probably the solution cannot be written as a formula.

Comment: There is not usually much difference between static and kinetic friction. Static friction applies at each turning point, when the spring stops and changes direction, so it does not make a lot of sense to ignore the starting amplitude. What might be more important though is how many coils there were in the sheath when you measured the friction. But I think you have figured that out.

Comment: The amplitude decay in your experiment does not seem to be linear. It looks closer to exponential, which shows that the horizontal-spring model is not suitable. I don't understand how you got the equation $A_n=A_{n-1}-0.4$ from your graph.

Comment: I have just realised that your measurement of friction is greater than the weight used in the experiment. (I think you must mean that the mass was 100g not 100mg.) If that was the case then I think the spring should not have made so many oscillations. It would also have an effect on the equation of motion.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that, it was 100g! I got the equation An = An-1 - 0.4 since every oscillation seems to have followed that but the first one, here is a gyazo of the tables which may illustrate this better https://gyazo.com/13a2369d0dd9f6d95c2c7c32728594ff . I figured that this was most likely due to static friction which is usually greater than kinetic in the first oscillation, but if that is not the reason why the first deviates, then I don't know what is. Moreover, I don't know if I can do anything with the knowledge that the friction changes depending on displacement other than mention it

Comment: *(continues from the last comment)* in the discussion of my lab report.

Comment: Btw, the equation An = An-1 -0.4 is not the measure in amplitude, but the measure of the change of amplitude, so there should be a delta before each "An".

Comment: Your eqn for amplitude decay $\Delta A_n=\Delta A_{n-1}-0.4$ is not reliable because it is derived from so few data points. For the horizontal spring you should get $A_n=A_{n-1}-c$ which is a different law; there is no reason to expect the relation you got. You are right, the variation of friction with displacement is too difficult to model. You can only mention it in your discussion. ... I don't know what you were supposed to learn from this lab : using a horizontal spring would have been more sensible, because the results are more easily modelled.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment before. And about the pattern, I just found it looking at the data, and it seemed reasonably accurate. I also mentioned that it might be a topic of further investigation, if the reader has the skills to further analyze the findings, didn't say much more about the pattern. When it comes to the topic of the lab, I choose this since it is similar to climbing rope, where the system is always critically damped, regardless of the height of the fall. This is due to the internal friction induced by the long carbon chains of the rope depend on its length. The initial...

Comment: idea seemed doable, since I knew that the friction was dependent on the number of coils in the paper sheath and I thought that this was an addition to the horizontal spring equation which would have a minuscule effect, but lo and behold, it made it unsolvable (for me at least). Oh well, I hope I will be given a break and not get penalized, since it was a hard topic for the level of physics and math we are studying, but if not, the topic was still cool and I learnt tons from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which you have got relates to the mass on a spring on a horizontal rough surface, as in your 2nd diagram. The constants $C_{1,2}$ depend on the initial conditions : ie the displacement $x$ and velocity $\dot x$ at time $t=0$. The constant $\delta$ takes account of the fact that $x$ might not be measured from the equilibrium position $x_0$ given by $kx_0=mg$. If the spring is released from stationary then $C_2=0$.

The two cases are half-cycles of a sinusoidal motion. The amplitude of each half-cycle decreases linearly. This can be shown from the work-energy theorem, eg s 4.1 of [this document](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/agnolet/Teaching/Phys_221/MathematicaWebPages/4_DampedHarmonicOscillator.pdf).  See also [A Piecewise-Conserved Constant of Motion for a Dissipative System](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9905057.pdf)
 and [Oscillator damped by a constant-magnitude friction force](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/390b/d07b58641a231a257437a00f94001f8c1606.pdf).

---

The motion of a spring sliding through a rough paper sheath is more difficult to analyse. As you have realised, the amount of friction depends on the number of coils in the sheath. This is proportional to the fraction of the spring in contact with it, which is $\frac{L}{L_0+x}$ where $L$ is the length of the sheath, $L_0$ is the natural length of the spring, and $x$ is its extension.

Assuming that the spring obeys Hooke's Law the equation of motion is
$$m\ddot x=mg -kx - sgn(\dot x)C\frac{L}{L_0+x}$$
where $C$ is a constant which depends on the roughness of the contact, and $sgn(\dot x)$ is the sign of $\dot x$. This equation probably does not have any algebraic solution. You would have to solve it numerically.

Comment: Are you sure that the x is in the denominator? Would this not mean that friction increases as the displacement from the equilibrium decreases? That is counter-intuitive. I agree with the fraction of L over L0, but surely the displacement should be multiplied by L on the numerator, or?

Comment: I am measuring $x$ downwards, so the total length of the spring is $L_0+x$. The longer the spring gets, the fewer coils in the sheath, and the less the friction.

Comment: Oh, I see now what you mean. I thought x was the displacement from the equilibrium, but if you use x as the length from when the spring is fully compressed, it makes sense! Moreover, I asked my brother with help on the equation but he couldn't solve it, I don't think it can be expected of me to solve this since it has to be done numerically (which is something we both had to google). I thought that this lab rapport was going to be much easier than it actually was, but the journey was great! Learnt a thing or two about the marvels of physics and mathematics.  Lastly, thank you for all the help!

Comment: One last question, why is the force of gravity "mg" in your equation but absent from the equation for the horizontal spring which I solved? What effect will it have on the solution if you solved the horizontal spring

Comment: For the horizontal spring the weight $mg$ is vertical and is balanced  by the normal reaction, so there is no acceleration vertically. The only unbalanced forces are spring force and friction horizontally, so the acceleration is horizontal. For the vertical spring gravity, spring force and friction are all vertical.

Comment: Oh ok, then I should redo my calculation of ma = -kz + friction to ma = mg - kx + friction, where friction is constant. And I will mention that the friction is not constant in the discussion, and mention that it couldn't be solved algebraically and hence it was opted to not be used, as my teacher suggested. Thank you for everything, and I hope you will have a great Christmas!