# Finding a path of beam in a gradient-index media

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, variational-calculus

I'm trying to find a polynomial that describes a path of a beam in a gradient index media.

It is a path of least time (Fermat's principle) meaning that it takes path that takes the least time to get from A to B, not the shortest one.

The velocity of a beam is non-linear. It's given by $v=c/n$, where $c$ is speed of light in vacuum and $n$ is index of refraction, which is a function of $y$.

Polynomial should be a function of `A.height`, `B.height`, width of the media and $n(y)$.

I need to solve this problem in Wolfram Mathematica, but I will value any tips.

[image: gradient index media]

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with the *Mathematica* computer language and should be closed.

Comment: Have you looked at the variational methods package? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/tutorial/VariationalMethods.html

Comment: Definitely a physics problem.  Have you figured out what equations you want MMa to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost exactly this problem is explained in detail in [these notes](http://www.physics.miami.edu/~nearing/mathmethods/variational.pdf). I refer you to those notes for the derivation. They conclude that it's better if $y$ is the independent variable, in which case you have to minimize the integral

$$\int n\cdot d\ell = \int f(y)\sqrt{1+x'^2} dy\\
\rightarrow\\
\frac{d}{dy}\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\left[f(y)\sqrt{1+x'^2}\right]=0\\
f(y)\frac{x'}{\sqrt{1+x'^2}}=C$$

Rather than a polynomial, it turns out that for the linear changing refractive index, $f(y)=n_0(1+\alpha y)$, there is a closed form solution of the path of the light:

$$y = -\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{C}{\alpha n_0}\cosh \left(\frac{\alpha n_0}{C}(x-x_0)\right)$$

Now you just need to solve for the values $x_0$ and $C$ so the curve goes through $A$ and $B$. I will leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Hi. You might be interested in [The amplitude of a damped spring with a weight during the 4 first oscillations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/374265) which involves some modelling of an experiment.